# Calling my Javascript function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following JavaScript / HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">Select
  <option value="150">USA
  <option value="50">Canada
  <option value="200">UK
  <option value="75">Kenya
</select>

<script>
    simpleCart.shipping(function myFunction(){
    var x = simpleCart.quantity();
    var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        if( x > 0 ){
             return y * x;
         } else {
             return 0;
         }
    });
</script>
```

Currently, I can't call `myFunction()` `onchange` for some reason. What do I need to change so that I can call `myFunction()`?

Comment: I tried to convert the text to something equivalent in better English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try wrapping the function like:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    simpleCart.shipping(function(){
    var x = simpleCart.quantity();
    var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        if( x > 0 ){
             return y * x;

         } else {
             return 0;
         }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: let ask u this is cart many item to change name of `myFunction()` is possibel?

Comment: @Henoktwo I don't quite know what you are asking, but if you are asking whether you can change the name for myFunction() to something else then the answer is yes as long as the also change its reference in the onchange event.